# How to save document to "Files" App in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I just created a PDF document in my app and I want to save the document on the device in a way that the "Files" app can access the saved document.

When you download a PDF document in Safari there is an option to save the document to the "Files" app, which is what I'm trying to do.

I Googled for several hours but wasn't able to find any useful methods.

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764198/7276810

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you have access to your `PDFdata` then you could present the user with a `UIActivityViewController` where they can then save it to `Files`, or share it with any of the other available options:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["Name To Present to User", pdfData], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: i have'nt any folder in "on my iphone", how to create a folder programmatically???

Comment: I am using PDFKit. How can I get PDFData and save pdf in files?

Comment: @EktaPadaliya check out my answer.

Comment: how to set custom file name of pdfData? Thanks

Comment: I use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54026866/how-to-name-file-stored-to-files-app-via-uactivityviewcontroller/54031361#54031361 Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1131021/joeybladb

Answer (score 18):

**Minimum of iOS 11**

The Files app was introduced in iOS 11. You will not be presented with the option to save to Files when you are on a version less than iOS 11. With that being said, documents can be downloaded to a variety of different apps depending on the settings available on the user's phone and the options you allow.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func savePDF() {
    guard let documentData = document.dataRepresentation() else { return }
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [documentData], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is an example of a way to save a document. You can't force it to be downloaded and show up in their Files app. You have to present a `UIActivityViewController` that shows options on what they can do with that document.

[image]

If you want to exclude any options shown on the `UIActivityViewController`, then implement `excludedActivityTypes` like so.

```
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [.airDrop, .postToTwitter]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `UIDocumentInteractionController`:

```
let doc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
doc.presentOptionsMenu(from:in:animated:)
```

There's an option named `save to Files`.