# Is it possible to save PDF file directly into the file without using UIActivityViewController or UIDocumentInteractionController iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to save a PDF document from URL into the device. Is it possible to save the PDF and access it from device file manager without using UIActivityViewController or UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: some answers were like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759148/download-pdf-and-save-to-the-files-in-iphone-not-to-the-app-data-swift

Comment: Think in distant past, I might have done the exact same thing!! If my memory serves me right, I created the PDF Using CoreGraphics. Once completed write/fetch the file using NSFileManager. Needless to say you will have to manually keep track of the File URL. To Create PDF check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html

Comment: My requirement is different. Already have a pdf and we can access it through its url.Then I need to download it and add some comments on the pdf pages. Then I need to resend it to the server.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you getting the PDF from remote or something?

Comment: yes... I will get the pdf's url from the server.. we can download and save it to the document directory or file. But the downloaded pdf will not shown when ever I try to open it through adobe reader app.

Comment: Well in that case! The toughest part is done away with :) Download the content of the PDF using NSURLSessions. I believe once downloaded, you will be provided with the temporary device URL. Just ensure that you move the contents of the temporary file to a more permanent location in your document directory.  You can access it later and edit as per your needs. Thats it!! Just remember you will be playing with NSData here all through..

Comment: I have done the saving task... Can we access the saved pdf from adobe reader app or phone's file manager?

Comment: No you cant. You cannot use any other app to access data from your app. Meaning App x cannot access data in App y and viceversa

Comment: This is my issue.. we can use the file after saving it into  file .   Ie using UIActivitycontroller and Documentinteraction controller.. right? .. is there any other way?

Comment: You can access your PDF file from adobe reader using UIActivitycontroller or Documentinteraction

Answer (score 6):

Add these 2 keys in your Info.plist: **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace** and **UIFileSharingEnabled**. And set YES as the value for both.

Now you will be able use the Files app to see any file saved by your app in Documents Directory.

Comment: can I open the saved pdf using adobe reader's URL schema after setting LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace and UIFileSharingEnabled. Any idea??

Answer (score 2):

> **Swift 5.0 and iOS13**

```
let documentController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(url: exportToURL, in: .exportToService)
self.present(documentController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*exportToURL* represent application local URL whichever file want to save into iPhone Files app.